# Read data from USB barcode scanner in .NET received event

Tags: c#, visual-c++, windows-services, hid, windows-console

I am using

1. Honeywell Orbit 7120 USB barcode scanner
2. Windows7 64bits

By using this component, I need a received event to my windows console application when a barcode scanner read then my receive event will fire. I have founded a serial port solution to Microsoft SerialPort class. But I need this class for HID (USB). I'd like to read the input using the USB driver and not the keyboard input.

How can this be accomplished using .NET? any ready libraries? I couldn't find anything.

I have tried lot but did not get any solution since last 5 days. **Please help me that how can I read data from my application when a USB barcode scanner read**

I have tried from here but device could not connect.
[C# and USB HID Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164055/c-sharp-and-usb-hid-devices)

Comment: did not find my device by vendor and product id 0x0C2E, 0x0204

Comment: Please don't just copy + paste your entire code base to a question and ask us to fix it. What *problem* are you having? What piece of code is causing it? You should be able to show us 5-10 lines causing the problem.

Comment: @Rob, scanner could not connect by by vendor and product id 0x0C2E, 0x0204

Comment: How you find this ProductID?

Comment: @Shohel Could you finally solve your issue? If not: I am using `Microsoft.PointOfService` for connecting a Honeywell Orbit 7120 scanner

Comment: @HermannSchachner, yes I solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use HID to communicate with your device, I advise you this library working very well: https://github.com/jklemmack/csharp-usb-hid-driver

Moreover, you can use this kind of code to detect new USB device plugged in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19962635/2486332